# Exceptions not showing when an error occurred laravel

Tags: php, exception, laravel-5.4

[image]
Error are not showing in the app.following are my config/app.php settings

'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'development'),

'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),

I have tried clearing config cache clear and optimize command 
.env file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:Pq/tS8K9qPwxyqPUz+efLhxhteuH1sgUuA/rPcG0msc=
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_LOG_LEVEL=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=lar_potal
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `APP_DEBUG=true` and `APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug` in **.env** file at the root of laravel.

The **.env** file you should have :

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:Pq/tS8K9qPwxyqPUz+efLhxhteuH1sgUuA/rPcG0msc=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=lar_potal
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

Comment: Its true and also true in config/app.php

Comment: It's not true in your question, you set `APP_LOG_LEVEL` to true  @AsifMehmood

Comment: it was working before but suddenly it stoped showing issues